# CMD / Batch file: Creating output/log file on a network share doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd, output, share

I want to make my CMD command's result be written to a txt file.

But creating the txt on a network share doesn't work.

Is this regularly impossible or do I have to chose a special syntax?

`...>\\192.168.0.1\testshare\log.txt` doesn't work. Creating the txt on a local drive works.

Access rights for the network share are given (share rights + NTFS rights):
Everybody could do everything (full control, write/delete).

TD

Comment: Use [`"\\server\share\path\file"` for Universal Naming Convention (UNC) names.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) Note doubled backslash `>\\192.168.0.1\testshare\log.txt yourCommand [parameters]`

Comment: He's actually using double backslashes, but stackoverflow renders double backslash as single backslash, need to use four backslashes to display two backslashes or use code markdown formatting. Edited question to display this.

Comment: Problem is not solved but analyzed successfully.

What I tried (and forgot to say):
I sent the CMD command to a remote system via WMI.

The CMD command works, it is okay!

But you can't connect to a remote system via WMI and then make another connect from the remote system to a third system (creating the txt on a network share would be the second connect).

It is forbidden.

Comment: `pushd "\\192.168.0.1\testshare" && someCommand > "log.txt" & popd`